# Calling onchange from purchase on partner

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I have this method

```py
@api.multi
def generate_purchase_order(self, ids, supplier_id):
    purchase_obj = self.env['purchase.order']
    purchase_line_obj = self.env['purchase.order.line']
    orders = self.browse(ids)
    origin = ", ".join(orders.mapped('name'))
    vals = purchase_obj.onchange_partner_id(supplier_id)
```

I want to call the onchange_partner_id method from a purchase on my supplier_id and receive values, but I do get an error message

```
vals = purchase_obj.onchange_partner_id(supplier_id)
TypeError: onchange_partner_id() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

as I work mostly with older versions of odoo it was possible to do it with syntax I trying to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onchange_partner_id doesn't require any additional argument to call it.

Change line from

```
vals = purchase_obj.onchange_partner_id(supplier_id)
```

to

```
vals = orders.onchange_partner_id()
```

Comment: There won't happen anything because `purchase_obj` is an empty recordset. It should be a foreach loop on `orders` and a single onchange call for every order.